# Inputting auto-incrementing, grouped, unique hashes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

Alright, here's what I've come up with so far:

```
SET @id=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 0) FROM leads);
UPDATE leads SET id=@id WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM leads) AS something WHERE hash IN ("hash1", "hash2")
);
INSERT IGNORE INTO leads (id, hash) VALUES (@id, "hash1"), (@id, "hash2");
```

Basically, I find the max `id` and add one, then update all indices if a hash is repeated. Finally, I insert the new hashes and ignore any duplicates.

Is this good? I have no idea. It works, but that's about as much as I know.

---

I've come up with a (hopefully) [better way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141467/efficient-workflow-queries-to-save-unique-information) to save unique company data, which now consists of unique hashes for each entity. Basically, there are multiple hashes associated with a company:

```
hash1: ABC Corp
hash2: ABC Corp
...
hash6: XYZ Corp
hash7: XYZ Corp
```

Consequently, I'm trying to create a `hashes` table that looks something like this:

```
hash (unique primary key), company_id (auto increments with the group)
```

For example, if I inserted the above example information, it should be reflected in the `hashes` table like so:

```
hash   | company_id
-------|------------
hash1  | 1
hash2  | 1
hash6  | 2
hash7  | 2
hash8  | 2
hash13 | 3
hash14 | 3
```

From there, things get a bit more tricky:

Say I want to add some new hashes, all to the same company but I don't know if the company is in the tables or not. To decide that:

1. If none of the new hashes exist in the `hashes` table, I want to create a new `company_id` for that group and use that id for these hashes and in subsequent insert statements.
2. If, however, any of the new hashes already exist in the `hashes` table, I want to merge all of the `company_id`'s into a new value in the `hashes` table and any other table that has rows referencing that id. Finally, I want to add any additional data using the new `company_id`.

Say (case 2) I have these hashes to add:

```
hash1  | ?
hash6  | ?
hash17 | ?
hash18 | ?
```

The result, after inserting them, should be:

```
hash   | company_id
-------|------------
hash13 | 3
hash14 | 3
hash2  | 4      -- company_id modified 1->4, hash2 appeared in the new hashes
hash6  | 4      -- company_id modified 2->4, hash6 appeared in the new hashes
hash1  | 4      -- company_id modified, (due to hash2)
hash7  | 4      -- company_id modified, (due to hash6)
hash8  | 4      -- company_id modified, (due to hash6)
hash17 | 4      -- added, new hash
hash18 | 4      -- added, new hash
```

I've done some research, it seems like a [grouped auto-incrementing column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119183/auto-increment-a-column-that-is-not-unique) is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044656/mysql-auto-increment-for-group-entries). Similarly, it seems like I can [use the result of a previous statement in a subsequent query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438823/mysql-using-results-from-one-query-to-use-in-another-query). I should also maybe look at [transactions](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/Transaction%20time%20validity%20in%20MySQL.pdf)?

As of now, my workflow looks something like this:

1. Select all `company_id`s where the `hash` equals any of the existing hashes
2. Select the largest `company_id` from the `hash` table
3. If no `company_id`'s exist from step 1, insert appropriate rows with an `company_id` of `max(company_id) + 1`
4. If one or more `company_id` exists, change all rows with those `company_id`s to an `id` of `max(company_id) + 1`
5. Perform steps 3 and 4 on any other tables that reference the `company_id`, writing most of the logic in PHP

As you can see, my method neglects MySQL almost entirely. I have a feeling I can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` effectively here, and I'm wondering if there's a way to skip step 5. But regardless of if it's possible, does this database design make any sense? Part of me thinks I'm going to have to do a portion of this with PHP but I am trying to make this as efficient as possible (I will be handling a large amount of data with whatever method is chosen).

Comment: I've edited your question with an example. Please check and modify if I have a mistake. Or just roll back the change if I grossly misunderstood what you want.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ What you added seems valid, I'm pretty sure we're on the same page.